# Where should the entity model be?

Tags: .net, architecture, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 in one of my projects.

The solution has 7 projects including Model and Repository. Since I already have database I am using Database First approach and creating POCO model objects.

I was wondering does it make more sense for Entity Model and auto generated entity classes to be in Model project or Repository project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on where you're happy having dependencies on EF4.1.

If its purely a data access thing - then the repository.  This is on the assumption that your POCO's are deliberately clean of unnecessary dependencies and that they are the data structures that will be passed between layers.

**Edit**

So, you need to think about responsibility and dependencies.

When Scott Millett (or whomever) came up with the 7 projects did he/they state what each of them was for?  If they did this should give at least part of your answer: if you think about what the EF does for you (or what you are going to use it for) against the purpose of each project.

The one thing that's not immediately obvious is where business logic lives - I'm assuming it's the model.  The thing about business logic is that you'll potentially want to re-use it a lot.  When you re-use it there's a good chance that the context of re-use will be different from the current one.

The danger is that those different contexts might have very different technical constraints - in such cases you want to have the least amount of dependencies possible; when you depend on something (like the EF) you also depend on what it depends on.  If your EF model depends on SQL (for example) then your logic is tied to SQL.

In addition the auto-generation could be an issue - if you ever decide you need to not auto-generate something.

Personally, I'd probably tend to craft my own POCO's for passing between layers, and use the EF purely within the Repository.

Comment: I understand there is no absolute answer for stuff like this. I was planning on passing these data structures between layers so I thought Model project was most suitable. What do you think?

Comment: Well what other layers do you have?  Your solution has 7 projects - are any of those the "business" or "logic" layers?

Comment: I have Controllers, Infrastructure, Model, Repository, Services, Services.Cache and UI.Web. I got this design from Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns book by Scott Millett.

Comment: I have decided to write Entities by hand and placing them in Model project and everything related to EF will be in Repository project. In this way EF dependencies are in one project.